# Unchecked conversion when popping stack Java

Tags: java, stack, compiler-warnings, unchecked-conversion

I'm new to Java and have a question about a warning:

My general code:

```
private Stack<ArrayList> stackFrame = new Stack<ArrayList>();
private ArrayList<Object> curBlocKList = new ArrayList<Object>();
...
curBlockList = stackFrame.pop();
```

I'm getting:

```
Parser.java:78: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
found   : java.util.ArrayList
required: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>
    curBlockList = stackFrame.pop();
```

I don't know how to syntactically make this work without a warning, as I'm working on a homework assignment and errors aren't allowed in compiling, and inserting

`@SurpressWarning("unchecked")`

is not allowed either.

What do I need to do to get rid of this warning?

Also, I want curBlocKList to hold a reference to the current top of the stack. Will this be accomplished by

```
curBlockList = stackFrame.pop();
```

or is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@SurpressWarning("unchecked")` should be put before the method prototype to work.

But you should try to change

```
private Stack<ArrayList> stackFrame = new Stack<ArrayList>();
```

Into

```
private Stack<ArrayList<Object>> stackFrame = new Stack<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parameterize ArrayList within your parameterization of Stack. Also, I recommend using List instead of ArrayList; you should [program to the interface, not the implementation](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html).

```
private Stack<List<?>> stackFrame = new Stack<List<?>>();
private List<?> curBlockList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```